# SelectList with Mechanize in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to set the value of a select list using Mechanize with Ruby. I can navigate to the page with the select list, grab the form using the .form method, and find the select list.

```
report_form =page.form('form1')
pp report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type")
```

Correctly returns the right object.

However, I'm still unable to set the value of this field! I've tried:

```
report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type").options.first.select
report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type").options[1].select
report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type").value = "Foo"
```

But when I then do:

```
pp report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type")
```

The value field is still empty.

Is there something I'm missing? Tips? Tricks? Better Mechanize docs than what live at http://mechanize.rubyforge.org?

Thanks!

Edit: The relevant HTML is:
The relevant HTML is:

```
<TD>
<select id="report_type" name="report_type">
    <option value="Foo1">Opt 1</option>
    <option value="Foo2">Opt 2</option>
    <option value="Foo3">Opt 3</option>
</select></TD>
```

Comment: The `report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type").value = "Foo"` should work for I'm understanding. The only to check this is to see the actual webpage.

Comment: I'm also unable to select any <option> in the HTML, but if I set the <select>'s value to an option not in the HTML it works fine.  MEH.  Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type").option_with(:value => "Foo").click
# now report_form.field_With(:name => "report_type").value should bee "Foo"
```

(via [1](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/test/test_multi_select.rb), [2](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/test/test_mechanize_form_select_list.rb))

Comment: are you looking at `.query_value` ?

Answer (score 3):

It's usually good enough to do:

```
report_form["report_type"] = "Foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

i ran into this same issue, nothing works for me either, but id like to clarify that im able to set the value to anything besides select options.

```
    report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type").value = "Foo1"
    report_form["report_type"]
    => "Foo1"
    report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type").value
    => "Foo1"
    report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type")
    => [selectlist:0x7c08ada type:  name: "report_type" value: []]
```

after submiting the form, the select is treated as empty, however if i do

```
    report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type").value = "anything not in the options"
    report_form.field_with(:name => "report_type")
    => [selectlist:0x7c08ada type:  name: "report_type" value: ["anything not in the options"]]
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the exact same problem, and setting the <select>'s value to anything not in the options works :|

Answer (score 0):

Foo is not in the select list, i think if you change it to Foo1 (or the others) it should work!?

Answer (score 0):

It actually turned out to be a bug in the Mechanize gem.  Make sure you're using v `0.6.0` or newer.